# Replace line containg pattern in Shell variable but keep line feeds

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, replace

Let's say I have the following variable:

```
var='a foo\nb bar\nc something'
```

Now I wan't to for example replace lines that contain 'bar' with '1 bar'. But keep in mind, that I want to keep my line feed signs, so I can save the output in a variable again. The result should look like:

```
$ echo $var2
a foo\n1 bar\nc something
```

I have tried to do it with Sed but the line feeds get replaced with spaces when I'm storing the output of Sed in a variable.

Comment: Make sure when you're checking the variable with echo that you put quotes around it.  `echo "$var2"`  will print with the new-lines, but `echo $var2` will not.

Comment: @jas That solved it, thanks. I feel dumb now.